# intersect interval of time by a character variable

Tags: r, rstudio, overlap, lubridate, intersect

I have a dataset with worker curriculum with:

- 2 time variable: `df$from` and `df$to`
- 1 name variable: `df$name`
- 1 bureau variable: `df$bureau`

I would like to generate a varible `df$varable` which sum 1 point every time there is an intersection of time for different person in the same bureau.
I am able to do intersect(df$from, df$to) but not to condition on `df$bureau`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Comment: `intersect` doesn't work the way you think it does.  It gives the intersection of two discrete sets, not interval overlaps. Look into the `lubridate` package for handling time intervals.

Comment: @Nathanwerth thank you very much, but i look into lubridate but i can't nonetheless handle the problem